# How does JavaScript determine the user's timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

How does JavaScript determine the user's timezone?

For example, if I run `new Date()`, the output is `Tue May 28 2013 11:51:03 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`. It knows that the offset is GMT-0700.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/), it doesn't.  Not reliably, anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's regarding `getTimezoneOffset()`, not the `new Date()` constructor. `new Date()` is accurate locally; `getTimezoneOffset()` is not.

Comment: Seems odd that they would work differently. Then again, it wouldn't be the first odd thing I found out about Javascript.

Comment: That blog post is six years old. I'd ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript in a web browser simply gets its time from a local system service. If a user in Hawaii has their computer set to Central Europe time, then JavaScript thinks it's running in Bratislava.

Comment: Thanks! I guessed that as well, but I wanted to make sure.